# why does my program loop infinitely?

Tags: java, loops, infinite-loop

My spell checking program doesn't give any error codes, just spell-checks the same words over and over, infinitely.
Is there a way to stop this infinite loop and put a cap on how many words it checks, for example, to end the code when ten incorrect words have been corrected?

I'm almost certain that the infinite loop is a result of this method here:

```
 public static void SpellChecker() throws IOException {
        dictionary = new Hashtable<String, String>();
        System.out.println("Searching for spelling errors ... ");

        try {
            // Read and store the words of the dictionary
            BufferedReader dictReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("dictionary.txt"));

            while (dictReader.ready()) {
                String dictInput = dictReader.readLine();
                String[] dict = dictInput.split("\\s"); // create an array of
                                                        // dictionary words

                for (int i = 0; i < dict.length; i++) {
                    // key and value are identical
                    dictionary.put(dict[i], dict[i]);
                }
            }
            dictReader.close();
            String user_text = "";

            // Initializing a spelling suggestion object based on probability
            SuggestSpelling suggest = new SuggestSpelling("wordprobabilityDatabase.txt");

            // get user input for correction
            while (!user_text.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
   // CleanString is a string full of words to be spell checked
                user_text = cleanString; 
                String[] words = user_text.split(" ");

                int error = 0;

                for (String word : words) {
                    suggestWord = true;
                    String outputWord = checkWord(word);

                    if (suggestWord) {
                        System.out.println("Suggestions for " + word + 
                        " are:  " + suggest.correct(outputWord) + "\n");
                        error++;
                    }
                }

                if (error == 0 & !user_text.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
                    System.out.println("No mistakes found");
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
             System.exit(-1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the value of `cleanString`?

Comment: put some sys logs and debug the values..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: user_text is supposed to be something entered by the user, right? But you never ask the user to enter anything. Also, don't, ever, use ready(). It doesn't do what you think it does. Also, the boolean AND operator is `&&`, not `&`.

Comment: @DarshanMehta it's initialized and set in another method; cleanString is a parse of the text on a website after it's been cleaned from HTML markup. ex: i'd enter the URL to google.ca, and cleanString would have text such as "google gmail get lucky search".

Comment: There's a lot of method calls here that you don't show, plus one entire class (`SuggestSpelling`).  I agree you should add some logging/printfs here to debug what is going on, but we'll also need to see the code you aren't showing if we are going to help you.  Also, we'll need to see the values you read in from the various inputs you use.

Comment: @JBNizet Hello, thank you for the comment. This is only one method from my program. The user is prompted for input from another method which stores some words in the "cleanString" variable

Comment: @markspace Hi. I was trying to follow the rules about minimal examples, so I apologize for not showing the entire code. I did not think it was necessary. Are github links accepted here? I could post the code there after I read the document on complementary debugging techniques.

Comment: You example has to be *minimal and complete.*  Posting a link to GitHub won't be minimal.  Manually make some new code that is complete and compiles but also demonstrates the behavior.  Don't forget that you need to include the input too.

Comment: Sure, but since you enter the loop if the user_text is not "q", and since you never ask for a new value in the loop, it loops forever (unless cleanString is equal to "q"). Hence the infinite loop.

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you! I had a prompt for the user to enter "q" to quit but somehow it got deleted. Can you post this as an answer so I can select it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never ask the user if he/she wants to quit or not, from inside the while loop. So `user_text` is initialized with `cleanString`, and never changes inside the loop, hence the infinite loop.